# Handing off delegate via Segue - bad pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

I have some Obj-c code that is working fine but I'm wondering if it utilizes an 'anti-pattern' and if there is an obvious better route that someone more experienced might take.

- ViewController1 is acting as the delegate for an object instantiated from a third party library. It is in the foreground.
- ViewController2 is coming to the foreground. During the segue, in `prepareForSegue`, ViewController1 sets the delegate of the object that it is currently acting as the delegate for to ViewController2, such that any subsequent delegate calls are received on ViewController2 while it is in the foreground.

This works. And it doesn't bother me too much. But it feels likes something where there might be a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you present/push ViewController1 to ViewController2 just change the delegate of your object to ViewController2. Just Like passing variables pass your delegate.

ex:
if you are using storyboard segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender   
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SEGUE_IDENTIFIER]) {
    ViewController2 *vc=(ViewController2 *)[segue destinationViewController];
    vc.OBJECT_IN_VIEWCONTROLLER1=OBJECT_IN_VIEWCONTROLLER2;
    vc.OBJECT_IN_VIEWCONTROLLER2.delegate=vc;
    }
}
```

Also set Object class and its delegate methods in ViewController2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fits your case but, how about make asuper view controller that manages the delegate stuff for you, and make your ViewController1 and ViewController2 a subclass of it? I will give you an example using a pseudo-code.

**Your super_view_controller.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //your delegate stuff, supposing the 3rd party lib object is singleton
    [[3PARTYOBJ sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)someDelegateMethod {

    //common stuff
}
```

At this point, if your view_controller1 and view_controller2 inherits from super_view_controller class, you dont't need to worry about changing delegate owner, it will happen automatically ... and if you need to do separate stuff on view_controller1 or 2, just override the delegate method:

**view_controller1.m** (super_view_controller subclass)

```
- (void)someDelegateMethod {

    //if you need common stuff, call super
    //[super someDelegateMethod];

    //or do your view_controller1 stuff here
}
```

(you don't need to override the delegate method on `view_controller2` if not necessary. The `super` method will be called instead)